# Undefined getSystemService() function for sensorManager object

Tags: android

My source code is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class ShakeEvent implements SensorEventListener  {
     private static SensorManager sensorManager;
     ...
     ...
     public static boolean isSupported (){
          sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

I receive error message that getSystemService function is undefined.
I tried to write this row also in such way:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

But then I receive error message that getContext() function is undefined for ShakeEvent object.
How should I write it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class doesn't seem to reference any `Context` object. `getSystemService()` is a `Context` method, so you need a reference to context object (like an `Activity`) when creating the `SensorEventListener`. Then you'll be able to call `context.getSystemService()`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class ShakeEvent implements SensorEventListener  {
     private static SensorManager sensorManager;
     private final Context context;

     public ShakeEvent(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
     }

     ...
     ...
     public static boolean isSupported (){
          sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Hi Clempr6r, it's great! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass Context object to this class and call getSystemService(..) on it

```
public class ShakeEvent implements SensorEventListener  {
    private static SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Context mCtx;
    ...
    public ShakeEvent(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }
    public static boolean isSupported (){
         sensorManager = (SensorManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)
         ...
    }
}
```